# Flutter double Fab use on docker

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using double FAB. But I don't know how can set fab position to docker.
If I use one FAB, I can do it like that:

```
floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.endDocked
```

but I used two fab so How can I do it that? Thats my FAB codes:

```
floatingActionButton: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:31),
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
              child: FloatingActionButton(
                backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
                child: Icon(Icons.import_contacts),),
            ),),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
            child: FloatingActionButton(
              backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
              child: Icon(Icons.play_arrow),),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUdn3.png)

Comment: Why are you using `stack`..!?

Comment: I dont know also onpressed method not work. How should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Am new to flutter and I want to make it as simple as possible

For vertical use `column` and for Horizontal use `row`, Let me show you how.

**For Horizontal:**

```
Row(
     children: <Widget>[
          Padding(padding :const EdgeInsets.only(right: 90.0, bottom: 5.0)),
          FloatingActionButton(
                      child: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
                      onPressed: () {}
                      ), //FloatingActionButton
          Padding(padding :const EdgeInsets.only(right: 90.0, bottom: 5.0)),
          FloatingActionButton(
                      child: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
                      onPressed: () {}
                      ), //FloatingActionButton
          Padding(padding :const EdgeInsets.only(right: 90.0, bottom: 5.0)),
          FloatingActionButton(
                      child: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
                      onPressed: () {}
                      ), //FloatingActionButton
             
                  ], //<Widget>[]

) //Row
```

**For Vertical:**

```
Column(
        children: <Widget>[
             Padding(padding :const EdgeInsets.only(right: 90.0, bottom: 5.0)),
             FloatingActionButton(
                         child: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
                         onPressed: () {}
                         ), //FloatingActionButton
             Padding(padding :const EdgeInsets.only(right: 90.0, bottom: 5.0)),
             FloatingActionButton(
                         child: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
                         onPressed: () {}
                         ), //FloatingActionButton
             Padding(padding :const EdgeInsets.only(right: 90.0, bottom: 5.0)),
             FloatingActionButton(
                         child: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
                         onPressed: () {}
                         ), //FloatingActionButton
             
                     ], //<Widget>[]

) //Column
```

It's just an idea on how to use multiple FloatingActionButtons, It's your wish how and where you'll use this idea...